# How get works symfony 4, cors, localhost, nginx

Tags: nginx, cors, symfony

i have such nginx config:

```
server {
    listen  127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name wtf;
    root /home/egor/PhpstormProjects/wtf/public/;
    client_max_body_size 32m;

    location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /home/egor/PhpstormProjects/wtf/logs/project_api_error.log;
    access_log /home/egor/PhpstormProjects/wtf/logs/project_api_access.log;
}
```

add_headers in / location was added according this manual: https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

After adding this blocks i get 403 or 404 for any url. I test, that if o remove all added blocks and leave only such block:

```
 if ($request_method = 'GET') {
 }
```

I still get same errors. How i can correctly add CORS support to my config?

Comment: What is in the nginx error log?

Comment: As i see http://i.imgur.com/xMQmQUk.png index.php don't used :(